# Excel VBA, check for latest version outside of network?

Tags: excel, vba, connection, version

I was wondering how could I make Excel check if it is the latest "version" of spreadsheet, outside of my network but with a internet connection, what do I need to do to set it up?
Maybe have a file or plain text hosted someplace with a number and have Excel though VBA check if the spreadsheet number is the same as the number hosted some where in the internet. I dont have hosting and I was wondering if I could use Google docs or Drive to host that file. Is that possible? If so, what do I need to do? Is there a code for that?

Comment: All of it is possible, but there is no standard way to check for workbook "versioning". It is always going to rely on exactly how you have your network (production and development) configured, what version control system you use, and how any of those configurations requires you to check. In general, since the whole of an Excel workbook isn't "source code" (i.e. all text), it can really only be checked into git, subversion, or any other CM repository as a binary file. You'll have to conform to your local policies.

Comment: You could try hosting a plain-text file in DropBox/Box and make it public.  Then access that file from your workbook.  You don't say anything about your VBA knowledge so it's difficult to say more about how that might work...

Comment: Does anyone know where Excel stores it's data from web source and how do I make it run when the spreadsheet is opens and than run a vba macro using Workbook_Open() ? Even though I selected "Refresh data when opening file" using the interface under Query Properities, Excel prioritize the VBA code under workbook_Open() . Is there anyway to "Call" the refresh though VBA?

Comment: I believe I found a solution using Google Spreadsheet and to my problem, I unchecked the box to refresh data when opening file then inside of Workbook_Open() included Activebook.Refreshall then the code that I want to run it.